# Ссылка на удаление себя среди других объектов на сцене

Tags: c#, unity3d

Можно вопрос как ссылаться на объект чтобы удалить конкретно этот объект среди других. просто у меня удаляются все.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{

    float timeFromLastClick = Time.time - LastClickTime;
    LastClickTime = Time.time;
    if (timeFromLastClick < 0.2)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

это проверка для 2 клика мышки если что

Comment: Это юнити? Просто из вопроса не совсем понятно, что такое gameObject

Comment: да.  Извините что не уточнил. gameObject это объект(я ссылаюсь сам на себя но почему то на сцене удаляются сразу все объекты а не 1 конкретный). я спавню их через Instantiate по нажатию мыши )

Answer (score 0):

Они удаляются все, где висит этот исходный код. Вы должны воспользоваться `void OnMouseDown()`. Обращаю ваше внимание, что на объекте должен быть какой нибудь компонент из физики.